# Probability of $P(X>max_{i}Yi)$, where X and Yi are independent exponential random variable

Tags: probability

I'm studying the textbook Introduction to probability models.
On the textbook, it solves the problem:

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be independent exponential random variables, with respective rates $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$. If that $X_i$ is the smallest of these then the probability is

$$P \{X_i=min(X_j)\} = \frac{\lambda_i}{\sum^{n}_{j=1}\lambda_j}
$$

which used the conditional probability

$p=P(A_1...A_n)=P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)...P(A_n|A_1...A_{n-1})$. I got this idea. However, I want to know what's wrong with my calculation, because they are different.

$P \{X_i=min(X_j)\} =P \{ X_i < min(X_j)\}$ for all $j\ne i$, then
$$P(X_i<X_1 \cap X_i<X_2...\cap X_i<X_n) = P(X_i<X_1)...P(X_i<X_n) \\
= \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_2}...\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_n}\\
= \frac{\lambda_i^n}{\lambda_1\lambda_2...\lambda_n} 
$$
the denominator should exclude i term.

Can someone let me know the mistake in here? Thanks.

Comment: Well, firstly, the independence of the random variables does not mean the events $(X_i<X_1)$, $(X_i<X_2)$, et cetera will be independent, as they all rely on the same variable $X_i$

Answer (score 1):

Well, mainly, the independence of the random variables does *not* mean the events $(X_i<X_1)$, $(X_i<X_2)$, et cetera will be independent, as they all involve the same variable $X_i$.

However, they *will* be conditionally independent when given $X_i$

So using the Law of Total Probability:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_i\,{=}\,\min\{X_j\})&=\int_0^\infty \lambda_i\mathrm e^{-\lambda_i x}~\mathsf P(x\leqslant \min\{X_j:j\neq i\}\mid X_i\,{=}\,x)\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\lambda_i\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-\lambda_i x}\,\prod_{j\neq i}\mathsf P\big(x\leqslant X_j\big)\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&~~~\vdots\end{align} $$